# Delete permission in custom role

Tags: azure-rbac

I have the following json for a custom role:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "custom-role",
        "description": "",
        "assignableScopes": [            
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "*/read",                    
                    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables/delete"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "*/delete"
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set "*/delete" under notActions and give delete permission only for "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables/delete"?